# Delphi Firemonkey Android getting call logs error

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Hello this is my code:

```
    function FetchCalls:string;
var
  cursor: JCursor;
  uri: Jnet_Uri;
CACHED_FORMATTED_NUMBER, CACHED_LOOKUP_URI, CACHED_MATCHED_NUMBER, CACHED_NAME,
CACHED_NORMALIZED_NUMBER, CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE, CACHED_PHOTO_ID,
CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, CONTENT_TYPE, COUNTRY_ISO, DATA_USAGE, DATE, DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER, DURATION,
EXTRA_CALL_TYPE_FILTER, FEATURES, IS_READ, LIMIT_PARAM_KEY, NEW, NUMBER, NUMBER_PRESENTATION,
OFFSET_PARAM_KEY, PHONE_ACCOUNT_COMPONENT_NAME, PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID, TRANSCRIPTION, TYPEX, VOICEMAIL_URI : integer;

  msgunixtimestampms:int64;
CACHED_FORMATTED_NUMBERx, CACHED_LOOKUP_URIx, CACHED_MATCHED_NUMBERx, CACHED_NAMEx,
CACHED_NORMALIZED_NUMBERx, CACHED_NUMBER_LABELx, CACHED_NUMBER_TYPEx, CACHED_PHOTO_IDx,
CONTENT_ITEM_TYPEx, CONTENT_TYPEx, COUNTRY_ISOx, DATA_USAGEx, DATEx, DEFAULT_SORT_ORDERx, DURATIONx,
EXTRA_CALL_TYPE_FILTERx, FEATURESx, IS_READx, LIMIT_PARAM_KEYx, NEWx, NUMBERx, NUMBER_PRESENTATIONx,
OFFSET_PARAM_KEYx, PHONE_ACCOUNT_COMPONENT_NAMEx, PHONE_ACCOUNT_IDx, TRANSCRIPTIONx, TYPEXx, VOICEMAIL_URIx : string;
begin
  uri:=StrToJURI('content://call_log/calls');
  cursor := SharedActivity.getContentResolver.query(uri, nil, nil,nil,nil);
  CACHED_FORMATTED_NUMBER:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('CACHED_FORMATTED_NUMBER'));
  CACHED_LOOKUP_URI:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('CACHED_LOOKUP_URI'));
  CACHED_MATCHED_NUMBER:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('CACHED_MATCHED_NUMBER'));
  CACHED_NAME:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('CACHED_NAME'));
  CACHED_NORMALIZED_NUMBER:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('CACHED_NORMALIZED_NUMBER'));
  CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL'));
  CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE'));
  CACHED_PHOTO_ID:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('CACHED_PHOTO_ID'));
  CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE'));
  CONTENT_TYPE:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('CONTENT_TYPE'));
  COUNTRY_ISO:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('COUNTRY_ISO'));
  DATA_USAGE:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('DATA_USAGE'));
  DATE:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('DATE'));
  DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER'));
  DURATION:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('DURATION'));
  EXTRA_CALL_TYPE_FILTER:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('EXTRA_CALL_TYPE_FILTER'));
  FEATURES:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('FEATURES'));
  IS_READ:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('IS_READ'));
  LIMIT_PARAM_KEY:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('LIMIT_PARAM_KEY'));
  NEW:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('NEW'));
  NUMBER:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('NUMBER'));
  NUMBER_PRESENTATION:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('NUMBER_PRESENTATION'));
  OFFSET_PARAM_KEY:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('OFFSET_PARAM_KEY'));
  PHONE_ACCOUNT_COMPONENT_NAME:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('PHONE_ACCOUNT_COMPONENT_NAME'));
  PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID'));
  NUMBER_PRESENTATION:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('NUMBER_PRESENTATION'));
  TRANSCRIPTION:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('TRANSCRIPTION'));
  TYPEX:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('TYPE'));
 while (cursor.moveToNext) do begin
  CACHED_FORMATTED_NUMBERx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(CACHED_FORMATTED_NUMBER));
  CACHED_LOOKUP_URIx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(CACHED_LOOKUP_URI));
  CACHED_MATCHED_NUMBERx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(CACHED_MATCHED_NUMBER));
  CACHED_NAMEx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(CACHED_NAME));
  CACHED_NORMALIZED_NUMBERx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(CACHED_NORMALIZED_NUMBER));
  CACHED_NUMBER_LABELx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL));
  CACHED_NUMBER_TYPEx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE));
  CACHED_PHOTO_IDx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(CACHED_PHOTO_ID));
  CONTENT_ITEM_TYPEx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE));
  CONTENT_TYPEx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(CONTENT_TYPE));
  COUNTRY_ISOx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(COUNTRY_ISO));
  DATA_USAGEx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(DATA_USAGE));
  DATEx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(DATE));
  DEFAULT_SORT_ORDERx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER));
  DURATIONx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(DURATION));
  EXTRA_CALL_TYPE_FILTERx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(EXTRA_CALL_TYPE_FILTER));
  FEATURESx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(FEATURES));
  IS_READx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(IS_READ));
  LIMIT_PARAM_KEYx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(LIMIT_PARAM_KEY));
  NEWx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(NEW));
  NUMBERx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(NUMBER));
  NUMBER_PRESENTATIONx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(NUMBER_PRESENTATION));
  OFFSET_PARAM_KEYx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(OFFSET_PARAM_KEY));
  PHONE_ACCOUNT_COMPONENT_NAMEx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(PHONE_ACCOUNT_COMPONENT_NAME));
  PHONE_ACCOUNT_IDx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID));
  NUMBER_PRESENTATIONx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(NUMBER_PRESENTATION));
  TRANSCRIPTIONx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(TRANSCRIPTION));
  TYPEXx:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(TYPEX));
    Result:=TYPEXx+CACHED_NAMEx+NUMBERx;
    end;
end;
```

and to use...
here is the usage method

Memo1.lines.add(FetchCalls);

But when i try to use this function i got this error :

"JAVA.LANG.LLLEGALSTATEEXCEPTION: COULDN'T READ ROW 0, COL -1 FROM CURSORWINDOW. MAKE SURE THE CURSOR IS INITIALIZED CORRECTLY BEFORE ACCESSING DATA FROM IT.

ANY IDEAS HOW TO SOLVE THIS??

thank you very much

Comment: First thing to check:  Have you specified the READ_CALL_LOG permission in your app manifest ?

Comment: Yes, the permission is ok.

Comment: Another idea? thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry, I can't help.  :(  I don't use Delphi for Android development precisely because getting even simple Android SDK examples to work is made difficult by the presence of FireMonkey which gets in the way of using platform native API's whilst failing to provide abstractions for common platform services, such as this one.  The possibility that it was a simple permissions issue was all I could suggest.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I solved your problem. It is really nice code who I used to copy and fixed the same exact error you have. 
first include

```
Androidapi.JNI.Provider, FMX.Helpers.Android
```

according to your delphi version. I used Delphi 10.1 Berlin in my case.

Second replace all

```
cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('XXXX'));
```

to

```
cursor.getColumnIndex( TJCallLog_Calls.JavaClass.XXXX );
```

as example for CACHED_NAME it will be

```
  CACHED_NAME:=cursor.getColumnIndex( TJCallLog_Calls.JavaClass.CACHED_NAME );
```

after compiling everything, it worked just fine. Another advice I will give you is to comment or delete the data you are fetching but you don't use. In the end of your code you return only TYPE, CACHED_NAME and NUMER. All other calls to get the data from the other fields are unnecessary.